# Spring Cloud app - zuul timeout after deploying on Tomcat

Tags: spring-cloud

I'm trying to set up a couple of services using Spring Cloud and everything seems to work fine up until the moment I deploy the Eureka client services to Tomcat. When I call a service through my gateway app, I get the following error:

```
o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
...
Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: hello timed-out and no fallback available.
...
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
```

It works perfectly from eclipse however. It even works when I run the discovery and gateway services from Tomcat, and run the Eureka client service from eclipse. But as soon as I run the same service on tomcat, I get the error.

I'm using Brixton.M5, Java 8 and Tomcat 8.

Again, the code seems to work, the problem is it doesn't work after being deployed to Tomcat.

I have one Tomcat instance for the Discovery and Gateway services, and a second Tomcat instance for the Eureka client services.

Here's some code and config..

**DiscoveryServerApp**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

DiscoveryServer - application.yml

```
# Configure this Discovery Server
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: discovery
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/discovery/eureka/

server:
  port: 1111   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
  context-path: /discovery
```

DiscoveryServer - bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: discovery
  jmx: 
    default-domain: com.example.cloud.discovery
```

**GatewayApplication**

```
@SpringCloudApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class GatewayApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

GatewayApplication - application.yml

```
# Discovery Server Access
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/discovery/eureka/
  instance:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

# HTTP Server
server:
  port: 4444   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
  context-path: /api
```

GatewayApplication - bootstrap.yml

```
# Spring properties
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service  # Identify this application
  jmx: 
    default-domain: com.example.cloud.gateway

encrypt:
  failOnError: false
```

**DummyApplication**

```
@SpringCloudApplication
@RestController
public class DummyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(DummyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping( path = "/hello-resource", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public String hello()
    {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

DummyApplication - application.yml

```
# Discovery Server Access
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1111/discovery/eureka/
  instance:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}} # Unique id for multiple instances

# HTTP Server
server:
  port: 3333   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
  context-path: /hello-context
```

DummyApplication - bootstrap.yml

```
# Spring properties
spring:
  application:
     name: hello-service  # Service registers under this name
  jmx: 
    default-domain: com.example.cloud.hello

encrypt:
  failOnError: false
```

Comment: What URL are you calling from the client/browser?

Comment: GET localhost:1111/api/hello/hello/hello yeah, I know, I just love greetings.. thanks for your quick reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by accident... turns out that the value of server.port needs to match the port of the Tomcat instance where it's deployed. It seems obvious now, but I thought Spring would somehow magically figure that out from the container it's running in. I guess it would be a good idea to read that configuration from an external location to handle different environments without having to make 'code changes'.

So anyways, the answer is: make sure your server.port in application.yml matches the port on the target container.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to help me with this!

Comment: Or just run the Spring Boot apps from the command line with the embedded TC server.

Comment: yes, but that is precisely what I'm trying to avoid.. I want to run multiple microservices with as few jvm's as possible

Answer (score 0):

You should point your bowser to port 4444 (gateway), not 1111 (eureka).

Comment: my bad.. my tomcat instance on 1111 has both the gateway and eureka server. When I run everything from eclipse, I do call it on 4444

Comment: Still, I can't see the third /hello in your example.
port is 4444.
first context path is /api,
then /hello from gateway
then /hello from REST.
Where is the third /hello from? 

Also, try to remove /discovery from eureka for debugging purposes and just point to the ip/eureka.

Comment: I see how that can be confusing.. I updated my config so now my call looks like localhost:port/api/hello-service/hello-context/hello-resource 
..I also tried your suggestion of moving /discovery to ROOT but unfortunately I still get the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Ok, `@SpringCloudApplication` wraps `@EnableDiscoveryClient` which causes `DummyApplication` to register itself with Eureka on startup.  You can confirm this is happening through the Eureka dashboard.

Assuming `DummyApplication` registers with Eureka as service name "hello-service", then Zuul / Ribbon will create a route for that service name.  Thus, your "/hello-resource" endpoint should be proxied through Zuul at:
 `http://localhost:4444/api/hello-service/hello-resource/`

Comment: Thanks for your input.. remember the Hello application is deployed under `/hello-context/` so the Zuul endpoint would look like `http://localhost:4444/api/hello-service/hello-context/hello-resource`